# Why I can't use acute trigonometric function in obtuse angles?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I need help at understanding why acute trigonometric functions only work with right triangles. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the ambiguity of "SSA triangles", where the law of sines gives two answers? Other than that possibility I don't really understand the question, since the trig functions are defined in reference to a right triangle.

Comment: It’s very unclear just what you’re asking. Could you rephrase?

Comment: @Lubin ,what I need is an explanation about why I can't use acute trigonometric functions to solve the angles of triangles that are not right-angled.

Comment: @manu You can, but not the same way; the relevant modifications are the law of sines and the law of cosines. These also apply to right triangles, but they simplify in that case (the sine in the law of sines becomes $1$ and the cosine in the law of cosines becomes $0$).

Comment: @Ian, maybe your second comment should be an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the trigonometric functions to find the angles and side lengths of non-right triangles. The modifications that are required are essentially the law of sines and the law of cosines. These still apply to right triangles, but they take on a simpler form (one of the sines in the law of sines becomes $1$ and the cosine in the law of cosines becomes $0$).

There are two special cases where you can be given three pieces of information and not necessarily be able to determine the triangle up to congruence. The first is being given all three angles and no sides; in this case you know the shape of the triangle but not its size. This is called AAA.

The other is knowing two sides and one of the angles not between those two sides. In this case, if you put point A at the origin, then you know exactly where point B is, but you only know how far point C is from point B, not necessarily where it is. As a result, depending on the exact numbers it can happen that there are two such triangles, one acute and one obtuse. This is called SSA.

Any other combination of three pieces of information can tell you all three sides and all three angles by using some combination of the law of sines and the law of cosines.

Comment: what are those modifications I can do to nonright-triangles to use trigonometric functions. And also why there is a limit on using only 90 degrees with triangles to use cos and sin without modifications.

Comment: @manu I told you: you use the law of sines and the law of cosines. You can't do it without modification because the trig functions are originally *defined* as ratios of side lengths in right triangles. When you go through to prove the law of sines and the law of cosines, you take your general triangle and draw imaginary right triangles to make use of the trig functions' definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The trigonometric functions are *defined* in terms of ratios of sides of a right angled triangle. $\sin\theta$ is defined to be the ratio between the side opposite an angle $\theta$, and the hypotenuse of a right angled triangle. These ratios change when you change the right angle to an obtuse angle, which is why they no longer hold.